# Reutilize CommandBar UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I utilize a CommandBar in several pages.
I've noticed that I'm repeating myself in this part of code:

```
<CommandBar  x:Name="MyCommandBar">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```

I've tried to create a custom control like this and just add the new `buttons` depending of the page:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TutorialManager.UWP.Views.Controls.MainCommandBarControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">


    <CommandBar >
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTitle}"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is when I add, for example, a new button in this custom control, it overlaps the first one.

There is some solution for this?

-- **Edit 1** --
First solution looks good, but when I add a button it goes to bottom:
[image]

```
<controls:CustomCommandBarControl Title="{Binding TituloPagina}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke">

    <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Save"  Foreground="White" />

</controls:CustomCommandBarControl>
```

-- **Edit 2** --
[image]
Looks better, but unfortunately I'm still having some issues.

1. New buttons that I add doesn't align to `more` button (even setting properties)
2. New buttons always show its label.
3. `More` button hides itsself when naviganting back and forward.
4. Looks like my `Custom Bar`inherits some properties from previously navigated bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new TemplatedControl and create a class like this one:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Content")]
public sealed class CustomUserControl : Control
{
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Content
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Content), typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>), typeof(CustomUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public CustomUserControl()
    {
        Content=new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomUserControl);
    }
}
```

in your generic.xaml you than define the control similar to this (Depending on your needs you neet to add margins etc.):

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomUserControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomUserControl">
                <CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                    <CommandBar.Content>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Margin="4,6,4,4">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       Margin="4,12,0,0" />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </CommandBar.Content>
                </CommandBar>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After a quick build you can use your new cotrol in a very easy way:

```
<yourNamespace:CustomUserControl Title="{Binding MyTitle}">
    <Button Content="Command1"/>
    <Button Content="Command2" />
</yourNamespace:CustomUserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the question, I've edited the question to add an image when I use your solution. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I've changed the orientation of the StackPanel. This should do the trick.

Comment: Almost there, see my edit 2, hope you can help me again.

Comment: I edited it a little bit, however i don't know exactly what you want so i am not sure if thats what you want. However you can play around with the code yourself until it fits your needs.

Comment: You're right, it's very difficult because `generic.xaml` for CommandBar have a wide context. Thanks.